# SSRS Dynamic Date Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm fairly new to reporting and need help with the following?

I have a report that has two date parameters statically set to default to the last financial year. i.e. the FROM parameter 01/04/2015 and the TO parameter 31/03/2016.
When the actual date next year is 01/04/2017 I need these parameters to change forward by one year, I know I maybe able to do it with a case statement and a getdate + dateadd .

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you have the two parameters set up already? How are these populated. Perhaps a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I have a small table which creates a year period based on certain dates which I then join onto the data then I use that to filter.

for instance:

1516
1617
1718

so if @year_period = 1516 then the previous year would simply be @year_period-101 and the future would be @year_period+101